# Prerequisite knowledge required to efficiently understand 'The Art & Craft of Problem Solving'

Tags: reference-request

I would like to improve as a Mathematician and I am currently doing A-Level Mathematics in England. I have come to learn that this book is a fantastic resource for anybody serious about a career in the subject.

In the next two years I shall be completing all 18 modules of the Edexcel syllabus which is made up of 7 'Pure' modules, 4 Statistics modules, 5 Mechanics modules and lastly, 2 Decision modules. I shall also be taking part in the STEP exams, used by Cambridge and Warwick to give offers to applicants.

I would like to know what level of knowledge is required of me as a reader and mathematician to be able to make the most of this book. The author states that the book is aimed at 'college-level' novices which would mean first year university students if I am correct.

So, for me, would this mean A-Level Mathematics and Further Mathematics would be enough to be able to start reading this book efficiently? I look forward to your replies.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to study this good book to complement your skills: Mathematical Circles: Russian Experience (Mathematical World, Vol. 7) by Dmitri Fomin Sergey Genkin, Ilia V and  Itenberg.

Answer (score 0):

The introduction to ACoPS addresses many of your concerns. The book is designed to be read non-linearly, and there are almost certainly many chapters you can already tackle. It turns out mathematical maturity can be developed in parallel to formal concepts.

I'd recommend reading the introduction, skimming through and identifying the chapters you feel more comfortable with, and then working through only those chapters. By the end of the first iteration, you will probably have learned some more maths and will be ready to repeat it again for new chapters.

*Disclaimer*: I have a very limited understanding of the mathematics coursework referenced in the original question, but am assuming it was asked by someone ~2 years from applying to an undergraduate program and studying a reasonably advanced curriculum.